# AS3 null-object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, null

So heres the code:

```
function playSound():void
{
    var channel:SoundChannel = sound.play();
    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onComplete);
}

function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
    SoundChannel(event.target).removeEventListener(event.type, onComplete);
    playSound();
}
```

I get the error on `channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onComplete);`
but I dont get it at the start, as a game runs for some time without the error, so Im suggesting theres a problem in a `onComplete` function or an event listener, however, all I tried had failed and Im stuck here for some time now.

I just decided to post it here and see if anybody can see the problem.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Sorry I havent included this right away.

Error:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   projectSnowFlake_fla::MainTimeline/playSound()[projectSnowFlake_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:275]
>     at
>   projectSnowFlake_fla::MainTimeline/playGame()[projectSnowFlake_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:269]
>     at
>   projectSnowFlake_fla::MainTimeline/gameLoop()[projectSnowFlake_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:156]
>   [UnloadSWF] projectSnowFlake.swf Test Movie terminated.

And heres the `sound` :

```
var sound:Sound = new MainSound();
```

Comment: `var channel:SoundChannel = sound.play();` what is your `sound` variable?

Comment: What error do you get? I'm thinking that the order in which you have registered the event could be a problem. But, not sure unless I look at the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your code, the only potentially issue is sound variable, can be null.

Have you instantiated sound variable?

If sound is valued, the method play (of variable sound) can return a null value?

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:**

Hi, view [this](http://blog.curiousmedia.com/?q=blog/flash-player-can-only-play-32-sounds-time) and [this issue](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/898418)

Comment: Hi, have you tested the result of method play()? It possible returns null?

Comment: just did, it might be a problem, it returns undefined

Comment: Exactly. If play return undefined, the object channel is setted tu null. In the next row you call addEventListener, method of channel object, but channel is null, so you can't call a method!

Comment: so how shoud I define play?

Comment: Plase post play method body

Comment: play() is integrated into as3 http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#play%28%29

Comment: @Dominiko: Check this: "This method returns null if you have no sound card or if you run out of available sound channels."

Comment: ok, do you have any idea how I can get arround that or maybe a bifferent method? thanks